# Android to set selected spinner item onto Edit Text View

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am new to android. I am displaying 5 strings in my spinner and i want when user selects a string it gets displayed to the Edit Text View.I am done with setting up the spinner items but i don't know how to display it on Edit Text View. I want to save it to Shared Preference also(I am allowing user either to select a text from spinner or manually can enter any text. I am able to set the custom text into the shared preference but don't know how to save the selected text)

```
  Spinner spinner;
        String[] alert = { "I am in danger", "Help Me", "Watch Out", "Look For Me",
                "Cover ME" };
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("EditValue" ,0);
            String myvalue = sp.getString("myvalue","");
            if(myvalue!=null || !myvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
               message.setText(myvalue);
            } 


        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spin_alert_message);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                alert);
        spinner.setAdapter(adp);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
            String   selectedItem = alert[position];
                    message.setText(selectedItem);


                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("EditValue" ,0); 
                    SharedPreferences.Editor spEdt = sp.edit();
                    spEdt.putString("myvalue", message.getText().toString());
                    spEdt.commit();




            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

        // for saving text that user can change as per need
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to Edit Text
        message.setText(preferences.getString("autoSave", ""));
        // adding addTextChangedListner() to the Edit Text View
        message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // saving text after it is changed by the user
                preferences.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Get selected value from `spinner` and set text int `EditText`

Comment: use `setOnItemSelectedListener` for the spinner to get he item name and set tit in `Edittext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this way:

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    selectedItem = alert[position];
    edittext.setText(selectedItem);


    SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreference("EditValue" ,0); 
    SharedPreference.Editor spEdt = sp.edit();
    spEdt.putString("myvalue", edittext.getText().toString());
    spEdt.commit();


   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   }
   });
```

Now whenever you want to get value from SharedPreference you will get by..

```
    SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreference("EditValue" ,0);
    String myvalue = sp.getString("myvalue","");
    Log.v("GetValue",myvalue);
```

**UPDATE:**

check it on oncreate() method..

```
   SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreference("EditValue" ,0);
   String myvalue = sp.getString("myvalue","");
   if(myvalue!=null || !myvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
      edittext.setText(myvalue);
   }
```

**NEWUPDATE:**

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spin_alert_message);

     SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("EditValue" ,0);
     String myvalue = sp.getString("myvalue","");
        if(myvalue!=null || !myvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
           message.setText(myvalue);
        } 



    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            alert);
    spinner.setAdapter(adp);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
        String   selectedItem = alert[position];
                message.setText(selectedItem);


                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("EditValue" ,0); 
                SharedPreferences.Editor spEdt = sp.edit();
                spEdt.putString("myvalue", message.getText().toString());
                spEdt.commit();




        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });


    // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to Edit Text

    message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // saving text after it is changed by the user


        }
    });
```

Comment: I have update my code, i want if user want to enter his own msg, he can do that in edit text view,which i was saving in Shared Preference and that was working just fine but not now and i am also giving my own 5 messages if he wants to select from any of those, it will get displayed to edit text and get saved in shared preference. But now, none of them is working :(

Comment: But 5 message will be stored in your array. And you have just save according to its array position

Comment: suppose i selects "watch out" from the spinner and if i closes the application or restarts the phone, i want the "watch out" text to be there on the edit text.

Comment: so after click on spinner you have set vale to edittext..So not working it?

Comment: sorry ?? didn't get it

Comment: After Selcect item on spinner the value of that spinner item set to EditText. So is it not working?

Comment: So not what issue occuring?

Comment: when i restarts the application, the text that i selected from the spinner is not there.

Comment: Yes...Because shared preference can save data throught application when you restart or uninstall application it will be clear.

Comment: so what should i do in that case ??

Comment: If you uninstall ur app it will be clear..So you can use database also

Comment: and before that , i was allowing user to add custom text into the edit text and i was saving that in shared preference, that time it was working absolutely fine. The application was showing text entered manually by the user even if application is restarted or even when phone is restarted

Comment: i don't want to use database + i will not uninstall my app

Comment: what to do ?? how to save in shared preference

Comment: you can see my answer...i did it

Comment: i have update see this  spEdt.putString("myvalue", edittext.getText().toString());

Comment: i am new to android, please tell me where to place that code " SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreference("EditValue" ,0);
    String myvalue = sp.getString("myvalue","");
    Log.v("GetValue",myvalue);"

Comment: Do you need to display edittext value in same activity or different?

Comment: in same activity only

Comment: SharedPreference sp = getSharedPreference("EditValue" ,0);
   String myvalue = sp.getString("myvalue","");
   if(myvalue!=null || !myvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
      edittext.setText(myvalue);
   }  
shall i put it in onItemSelectedListner or outside the curl ??

Comment: you should out outside onItemSelectedListner on oncreate() method

Comment: i've updated my answer, please have a look, am i doing it right ?

Comment: when is closed the application and starts again, there is no selected over there + its showing warning  at "if(myvalue!=null || !myvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {" on "myvalues" in onCreate i.e. "Null pointer access: The variable myvalue can only be null at this location"

Answer (score 3):

You can use spinner setOnItemClickListener like below

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                    edittext.setText(selected);
            }
        });
```

Comment: will it be a setOnItemClickListner or setOnItemSelectListner

Comment: @bhanukaushik Its OnItemSelectedListener().

Comment: @bhanukaushik You can use both. I have used setOnItemClickListener in my projects.

Answer (score 1):

In the `onItemSelected` method, get the position of the item selected the way @Mayuri has mentioned, or

```
String selected = alert[position];
editText.setText(selected);
```

Comment: i have updated the code that i have implemented and its working but the selected string that is getting displayed on the Edittext is not getting saved to the Shared Preference.

Comment: to save it to the sharedpreference in the same onItemSelected listener, write this: Editor edit = sp.edit(); edit.putString("key",selectedString);edit.commit();

Answer (score 0):

set and implement `OnItemSelectedListener()` for the spinner and inside the `onItemSelected` method get the selected item and set the `EditText.setText()`

Answer (score 0):

Implement this way: **OnItemSelectedListener()**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    selectedItem = alert[position];
    edittext.setText(selectedItem);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
});
```